# How do I run a gradle task that uses npm in Intellij

Tags: node.js, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a a project that I use the gradle-node-plugin to run npm install. When I run from the command line, everything works fine. When I run from Intellij I get...

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':npmInstall'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'npm''

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
Cause: error=2, No such file or directory
1:17:15 PM: Task execution finished 'bootRun'.
```

Seems to be related to the Gradle Daemon running because sometime IJ causes it to get hosed on the terminal so I have to kill it before it will work again.

Comment: Seems that `npm` is not in PATH when running from IDE. What is your OS and what is IDE version? Try if settings PATH in gradle script helps: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-115426#focus=streamItem-27-610182-0-0

Comment: You are talking about the plugin with id 'com.moowork.node', right?
I have no problem using that plugin even on machines that do not have npm installed previously. What happens if you do as told by the error message and run with --stacktrace? Also can you share (relevant parts of) your build file?